# .NET Custom IP STS

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, saml

I have done some searching around both on here and also the web. I need to have SharePoint 2013 use an IP STS for authentication, but I can't use ADFS because the AD does not have all the users. I need to write my own IP STS but can't find any good examples.

I have found ThinkTecture's Embedded STS. While I can certainly dig in to an open-source project to see if it can do what I need, I just can't believe there aren't any examples of how to do this on the web. All the examples on MSDN assume you want to use ADFS with SharePoint which is more than presumptuous, and frankly annoying.

Does anyone know of any good resources I can use to roll my own IP STS other than wading in an open-source project from the get-go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to write your own? - there are a lot of other STS e.g. OpenAM, PingFederate etc. that you can use in place of ADFS. shibboleth is an widely used open-source STS that sits on top of a variety of identity repositories.

Writing a secure STS is hard.

Not sure what version of VS you have but VS 2010 had the ability to create a STS framework for you (plus templates) that you could build on and I suspect VS 2012 also had if you added the "Identity and Access Tool"?

Also: [Building a simple custom STS using VS2012 & ASP.NET MVC](http://chris.59north.com/post/2013/04/09/Building-a-simple-custom-STS-using-VS2012-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) among others.

Comment: I actually don't want to write one. My client doesn't have that kind of time. I'd prefer to piggy back on something else, but I had reached an impasse on the ol' Google. Thank you for the great leads. This gives me something to work through.

Comment: OK - just remember that SP requires WS-Fed not SAML-P. simpleSAML php is another good one but not sure if they support WS-Fed?